# Describe the subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ of the form: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the real cube root of $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Describe the subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ of the form: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the real cube root of $2$.

Let $\alpha$ be the real cube root of $2$, and consider $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. As well as $\alpha$, the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ must contain $\alpha^2$. We show that $$\alpha^2\neq j+k\alpha \text{ for } j,k \in \mathbb{Q}.$$ For a contradiction, suppose that $\alpha^2=j+k\alpha$. Then $$2=\alpha^3=\alpha(j+k\alpha)=j \alpha + k \alpha^2=j\alpha + k(j+k\alpha)=j\alpha+jk+k^2\alpha=jk+(j+k^2)\alpha.$$ Therefore $(j+k^2)\alpha=2-jk$. Since $\alpha$ is irrational, 
$j+k^2=0=2-jk.$ Note that $j+k^2=0 \iff -j=k^2$, so $$j+k^2=0=2-jk \iff k^3=2,$$ which is a contradiction because $k\in \mathbb{Q}$.

\null
In fact, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is precisely the set of all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $$p+q\alpha + r\alpha^2, \text{ where } p,q,r\in \mathbb{Q}.$$ To show this, we prove that the set of such elements is a subfield. We will show that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ can be expressed in this way. Set 
$$X=\{p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2 | p,q,r \in \mathbb{Q} \}.$$

- $X$ is a subgroup of the additive group $(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha), +)$.
- $1\in X$ is an identity element for multiplication.
- Multiplication between to elements: 
  $$ (p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2)(p'+q'\alpha+r'\alpha^2) = p'p+(p'q+pq')\alpha+(p'r+pr'+qq')\alpha^2 +(r'q+rq')\alpha^3+rr'\alpha^4 $$

I know that I can't have $\alpha^4$, so I need to rewrite it. How would I do that?

Answer: $$\alpha^4=2\alpha$$

How would I approach find the inverse of $p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2$?

Comment: $\alpha^4=\alpha^3\times\alpha$...

Comment: So i can simply say $\alpha^4=2\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, that is it

Comment: Perfect. Now how would I approach find the inverse element?

Comment: Inverses are much trickier, and I would be surprised if you were asked to do this problem without being shown some similar example beforehand.

Comment: The ones I have done before involve square roots or complex numbers. So finding those inverses were easy since we know the conjugates in both cases. But this one has neither.

Comment: Hrm, OK.  Maybe whoever posed this problem to you didn't realize how much trickier this case was...or maybe I'm just missing some idea that makes this easier than I thought.

Comment: Wait if this is just a quadratic can't I just use the quadratic formula?

Comment: @Shiyue: Given that my answer more or less completely answers the question, I am puzzled by your bounty.  Can you explain what more you want from an answer?

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry just saw this!! > < I'm stuck at finding the inverse...

Answer (score 5):

Since $\alpha^3=2$, $\alpha^4=\alpha^3\cdot\alpha=2\alpha$.

Inverses require a lot more cleverness.  Here's one possible approach.  Note that $X$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}$, and that for any $x\in X$, the map $\mu_x(y)=xy$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $X\to X$.  If $x\not=0$, furthermore, $\mu_x$ is injective.  But any injective linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself is also surjective.  It follows that $1$ is in the image of $\mu_x$, which says exactly that $x$ has an inverse.

(In principle, using Cramer's rule to compute the inverse of the linear map $\mu_x$, you can use this argument to explicitly write down a formula for $x^{-1}$, but it will be quite complicated!)

Comment: I can't believe this brilliant proof had no upvote!

Answer (score 3):

The equation $X^3 - 2 = 0$ has three roots, namely $\alpha$, $j\alpha$ and $j^2\alpha$, where $j$ is a cubic root of unity. Therefore $p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2$ has two conjugates: $p+qj\alpha+rj^2\alpha^2$ and $p+qj^2\alpha+rj\alpha^2$. The product of the three will be rational. The inverse can be written:
$$\frac{1}{p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2}
= \frac{(p+qj\alpha+rj^2\alpha^2)(p+qj^2\alpha+rj\alpha^2)}
{(p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2)(p+qj\alpha+rj^2\alpha^2)(p+qj^2\alpha+rj\alpha^2)}
= \frac{(p^2-2qr)+(2r^2-pq)\alpha+(q^2-pr)\alpha^2}
{p^3+2q^3+4r^3-6pqr}$$
If you want to know more, you should read a course on Galois theory, for example Milne's lecture notes which are available online: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FTe6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let me first reformulate precisely your question: if *a* is a real cubic root of 2, you know that every element *x* of the field **Q**(*a*) can be written uniquely as *x* = p + q*a* + r*a*^2, with p, q, r in **Q**, and you want to compute an analogous "polynomial" expression for the inverse *x*^-1 ?

The answer is very simple if we go back to the classical "polynomial" description of the field **Q**(*a*), which is the beginning of the theory of algebraic extensions of a field. I recall it here. Denote as usual by **Q**[*a*] the ring generated by **Q** and *a*. By the universal property of the ring of polynomials **Q**[X], we have a ring homomorphism *h* from **Q**[X] to **Q**[*a*] which sends X to *a*. By construction, *h* is surjective, and its kernel is obviously the principal ideal generated by X^3 - 2, because this polynomial is irreducible over **Q** (the shortest proof uses Eisenstein's criterion; a longer proof is the one you gave for the "polynomial" description of the elements of **Q**(*a*)). Thus we have that **Q**[*a*] is isomorphic to the quotient **Q**[X]/(X^3 - 2), which is a field since the ideal (X^3 - 2) is maximal because  X^3 - 2 is irreducible. So **Q**[*a*] = **Q**(*a*). Note that this gives again the aforementioned "polynomial" description of the elements of **Q**(*a*). But it gives more if we detail the proof of the existence of inverses (maximality of (X^3 - 2), etc.) : the ring **Q**[X] being a UFD, the Bézout identity is available, i.e.  polynomials f(X) and g(X) are coprime iff there exists u(X) and v(x) such that : u(X)f(X) + v(X)g(X) = 1. Here take f(X) = p + qX + rX^2, which is coprime to g(X) = X^3 - 2. Applying *h* , we get u(*a*).f(*a*) = 1 , i.e. u(*a*)is the inverse we are looking for.

Concretely, given f(X), we must find u(X): this is the euclidian algorithm applied to the computation of the Bézout identity, see e.g. www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/.../divgcd.pdf               ¤

Comment: $\LaTeX$ please!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand a lot better from your answer! :)