# prove that subsets are fields (or not) of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm in a course in fields/galois theory using DJH Garling's book but just starting I'm struggling with this question.

Which of the following subsets are subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.

i) $$\{a+bi: a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
ii)$$\{a+\omega b: a,b \in \mathbb{Q}. \omega=1/2 (-1+\sqrt{3}i) \}$$
iii) $$\{a+2^{1/3}b: a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$
iv) $$\{a+2^{1/3}b+4^{1/3}c: a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$

I proved the first is a field but the third is not. The issue with the second and last sets is that I proved all requirements (axioms of groups under + and *) but the multiplicative inverse for nonzero elements.

In ii) and iv), I assumed that the inverse must be the same as in $\mathbb{C}$ conjugate divided by norm but I couldn't figure out the algebra to write the inverse as an element of the set.

I found similar questions here but not exactly and some of them use tools that are yet to be learnt in the course I assume. This is the first class and the very beginning of the book so I assume that a pretty elementary proof is required.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: for ii), $\dfrac1{a+\omega b}=\dfrac{a+\overline \omega b}{(a+\omega b)(a+\overline \omega b)}=\dfrac{a-b-b\omega}{a^2+b^2-ab}$ using $\overline \omega = \omega^2$ and $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$

Comment: An explicit formula for inverses in (iv) is going to be a huge mess.  If you have some basic linear algebra available it is not too hard to prove that inverses exist, though.  See the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486494/describe-the-subfields-of-mathbbc-of-the-form-mathbbq-alpha-where for more.

Comment: It is precisely the fourth example which shows the limitation of algebraic manipulation. The way to find the inverse here requires a systematic method or theory.

Comment: You may observe that $p(x) =x^3-2$ is coprime to $q(x)=a+bx+cx^2$ and hence we have polynomials $r(x), s(x) $ with $r(x) p(x) +s(x) q(x) =1$. Now put $x=2^{1/3}$.

Comment: By the way, contrary to your assumption, the "conjugates" of $a+2^{1/3}b+4^{1/3}c$ are not its complex conjugate, which is itself since it's in $\mathbb R$

Comment: For (ii), it's *much* easier to manipulate things if you note that any element of your subset can also be written in the form $a+b \sqrt 3 i$, with $a, b \in \Bbb Q$, and similarly, any element that can be written in this form is a member of your subset.  I'm guessing you can find the inverse of that element with relative ease.